# Uniqueness of Linear Functional

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let, V be a finite dimensional real vector space of dimension n$>1$ and let W$\subset$V be a subspace of dimension n-1. A linear map from V to $\mathbb{R}$ is called a linear functional on V. Which of the following statement is necessarily true?

(a) There does not exist any linear functional on V such that W is the kernel of that linear functional.

(b) W is the kernel of a unique linear functional on V.

(c)W is the kernel of a linear functional on V.

(d) There exist a non-zero linear functional on V whose kernel strictly contains W.

My Approach: By the defination of linear functional, I've discarded option (a) and (d). I'm trying to prove that W is the kernel of a unique linear functional on V but that's where I've stuck on.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take  a basis for $W$ and extend it to a basis for $V$. Now you can easily find a  linear functional with kernel $W$.

Comment: $f$ and $2f$ have the same kernel.